# A python relative import conundrum - why does this not work?

Tags: python, flask, import, pycharm

I have a strange relative import problem which I'm at pains to understand. Here's my project structure:

```
project
  bot_app
    app
      __init__.py
      stuff.py
  web_app
    app
      __init__.py
      other_scripts.py
      etc.py
      app_to_run.py
```

Everything works when I run my web app (its flask) with Gunicorn or Flask Run, which finds an app instance in **init**.py

```
CreateApp(ConfigFile)
    app = Flask() 
    functions_which_build_app()
    extension.init_app(app)
    return app
```

Tn my `app_to_run.py` script I'm trying to create a test app instance with another config, then run it, like so. So I basically run python run_test_app() in PyCharm (by clicking Run)

```
from app import create_app
from app.config import TestConfig


def run_test_app():
    test_app = create_app(config=TestConfig)
    test_app.run(host='localhost', port='5000', debug=True, load_dotenv=True)

run_test_app()
```

But I get an error:

```
from app import create_app
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from 'app' (C:\Users\PycharmProjects\project\bot_app\app\__init__.py)
```

I see its trying to grab from`bot_app\app\` even though the script is in `web_app\app` which I don't understand? So I change it:

```
from web_app.app import create_app
from web_app.app.config import TestConfig


def run_test_app():
    test_app = create_app(config=TestConfig)
    test_app.run(host='localhost', port='5000', debug=True, load_dotenv=True)

run_test_app()
```

Now i get an error that it can't find `app.loggers` even though its definitely there since it runs normally. I'm running this in pyCharm and I simply don't get it?

```
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\project\web_app\app\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app.loggers import logger, debug
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.loggers'
```

Is this to do with PyCharm? Do I need to setup a run environment specifically for this instance?

Comment: refer this https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

Comment: `CreateApp` or `createapp`? Is there a factory function in `__init__.py` you didn't list?